# redis 6 cluster eviction happening though memory not full

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a Redis 6 cluster for which I'm seeing keys being evicted although the memory usage is way bellow the max-memory. This started happening suddenly without any changes in the redis configuration. After restarting the cluster I noticed that the memory usage remains pretty low and eviction is happening quite frequently. The eviction policy in use is volatile-ttl.
Also another thing I'm seeing is the number of connected clients hits the upper limit(10K in this case)
Hoping someone could help me figure out what could be the issue here.
Sharing here the output of the info cmd for both Redis master and slave:

```
=============================================================
MASTER
-------------------------------------------------------------

# Server
redis_version:6.0.15
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:cc78c4070c92a925
redis_mode:cluster
os:Linux 4.19.0-18-amd64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:8.3.0
process_id:31660
run_id:c83d70b769c8c2b0b278c4849587da200d9b1d69
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:101519
uptime_in_days:1
hz:40
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:13426126
executable:/usr/bin/redis-server
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf
io_threads_active:0

# Clients
connected_clients:5391
client_recent_max_input_buffer:13
client_recent_max_output_buffer:102520
blocked_clients:0
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0

# Memory
used_memory:458049760
used_memory_human:436.83M
used_memory_rss:484409344
used_memory_rss_human:461.97M
used_memory_peak:3368511544
used_memory_peak_human:3.14G
used_memory_peak_perc:13.60%
used_memory_overhead:229774597
used_memory_startup:1481432
used_memory_dataset:228275163
used_memory_dataset_perc:50.00%
allocator_allocated:456409640
allocator_active:491253760
allocator_resident:574595072
total_system_memory:6781198336
total_system_memory_human:6.32G
used_memory_lua:44032
used_memory_lua_human:43.00K
used_memory_scripts:216
used_memory_scripts_human:216B
number_of_cached_scripts:1
maxmemory:3221225472
maxmemory_human:3.00G
maxmemory_policy:volatile-ttl
allocator_frag_ratio:1.08
allocator_frag_bytes:34844120
allocator_rss_ratio:1.17
allocator_rss_bytes:83341312
rss_overhead_ratio:0.84
rss_overhead_bytes:-90185728
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.06
mem_fragmentation_bytes:28639968
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:117440512
mem_clients_slaves:20520
mem_clients_normal:110314909
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:56152418
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1640801019
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:50
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:52649984
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:35796569
total_commands_processed:590867133
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:8389
total_net_input_bytes:89738011195
total_net_output_bytes:3312332964610
instantaneous_input_kbps:1313.33
instantaneous_output_kbps:31123.46
rejected_connections:51895108
sync_full:8
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:8
expired_keys:39441
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:12799
evicted_keys:550280
keyspace_hits:117987159
keyspace_misses:152648916
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:33060
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:0
total_reads_processed:276379956
total_writes_processed:250731383
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:1
slave0:ip=10.201.0.168,port=6379,state=online,offset=58027726955,lag=0
master_replid:9282caa3cb5d0ba02fa578afd903b1b50d9716bb
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:58028193108
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:1
repl_backlog_size:104857600
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:57923335509
repl_backlog_histlen:104857600

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:38247.933362
used_cpu_user:14446.626778
used_cpu_sys_children:8.626066
used_cpu_user_children:54.621343

# Modules

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:1

# Keyspace
db0:keys=3983,expires=3981,avg_ttl=57014903


=============================================================
SLAVE
-------------------------------------------------------------


# Server
redis_version:6.0.15
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:cc78c4070c92a925
redis_mode:cluster
os:Linux 4.19.0-18-amd64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:8.3.0
process_id:29073
run_id:183f5499850315dd96abee0a68a70c241ed74e24
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:101622
uptime_in_days:1
hz:80
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:13426213
executable:/usr/bin/redis-server
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf
io_threads_active:0

# Clients
connected_clients:9593
client_recent_max_input_buffer:8
client_recent_max_output_buffer:58816
blocked_clients:0
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0

# Memory
used_memory:1217825032
used_memory_human:1.13G
used_memory_rss:987283456
used_memory_rss_human:941.55M
used_memory_peak:4488677824
used_memory_peak_human:4.18G
used_memory_peak_perc:27.13%
used_memory_overhead:355842079
used_memory_startup:1480408
used_memory_dataset:861982953
used_memory_dataset_perc:70.87%
allocator_allocated:1066261000
allocator_active:1194848256
allocator_resident:1293684736
total_system_memory:6781202432
total_system_memory_human:6.32G
used_memory_lua:45056
used_memory_lua_human:44.00K
used_memory_scripts:216
used_memory_scripts_human:216B
number_of_cached_scripts:1
maxmemory:3221225472
maxmemory_human:3.00G
maxmemory_policy:volatile-ttl
allocator_frag_ratio:1.12
allocator_frag_bytes:128587256
allocator_rss_ratio:1.08
allocator_rss_bytes:98836480
rss_overhead_ratio:0.76
rss_overhead_bytes:-306401280
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.93
mem_fragmentation_bytes:-78632296
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:117440512
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:236375199
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:48510107
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1640800985
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:26
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:252465152
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:12275794
total_commands_processed:512831691
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:2324
total_net_input_bytes:79842456649
total_net_output_bytes:2982825808242
instantaneous_input_kbps:203.09
instantaneous_output_kbps:9802.07
rejected_connections:36554824
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:107594962
keyspace_misses:143931706
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:30268
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:0
total_reads_processed:193620091
total_writes_processed:183944221
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0

# Replication
role:slave
master_host:10.201.1.246
master_port:6379
master_link_status:up
master_last_io_seconds_ago:1
master_sync_in_progress:0
slave_repl_offset:58070165068
slave_priority:100
slave_read_only:1
connected_slaves:0
master_replid:9282caa3cb5d0ba02fa578afd903b1b50d9716bb
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:58070165068
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:1
repl_backlog_size:104857600
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:57965307469
repl_backlog_histlen:104857600

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:31353.531339
used_cpu_user:11827.307506
used_cpu_sys_children:3.945530
used_cpu_user_children:16.849249

# Modules

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:1

# Keyspace
db0:keys=4432,expires=4430,avg_ttl=0
(0.50s)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you did hit max memory, so the expiration policy was triggered:

```
used_memory_peak_human:3.14G
```

used_memory: Total number of bytes allocated by Redis using its allocator (either standard libc, jemalloc, or an alternative allocator such as tcmalloc)
used_memory_human: Human readable representation of previous value

which is greater than

```
maxmemory_human:3.00G
```

maxmemory: The value of the maxmemory configuration directive ( the limit set on memory that redis can use)
maxmemory_human: Human readable representation of previous value

It may be a good idea to track your redis usage over time using Redis Insight or some tool like prometheus to see if you have a spike of writes that are putting you over the limit.